# how to set java version path to firefox in runtime

Tags: java, java-7, java-6

Please anyone help me to set java version path in Runtime.

i installed two java versions in different directories.but i need to use java 7 compile code to execute appliction using java6 version.

I need to set java 6 path for firefox browser could any one help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you run the application with Java 7?

Comment: still can not understand your meaning

Comment: I am automating adn=min tool which supports to java 6.and also basic requirement to test this application using java 6

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Java Control Panel->in Java tab click on View->from there you can enable or disable the specific JRE.
You can check here.
http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/otherFeatures/version.html

Answer (score 0):

In Windows registry  set the plugin version You want to be used:

- Windows(32bit):

  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=xx.xx.xx`
- Windows (64bit):

  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=xx.xx.xx`

  [image: Registry example]